# Как сделать чтобы скролл оставался вверху, при прокрутке мышкой?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, mouse-event, mousewheel

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать первый слайд с этого сайта http://skyservice2016.ru/
У меня получилось сделать чтобы слайдер скроллился, но как быть с тем, что бы прокрутка не скроллилась, не придумаю.

Вот код того, что у меня вышло. slide_animated - это наш первый слайд, он должен подниматься вверх, slide-2 - это следующая страница, которая поднимается за slide_animated.

```
 $('body').on('mousewheel', function(event,type) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 924)
    {
        var el = $('.slide_animated');
        if (type == 1 && window.pageYOffset == 0)
        {
            if (el.hasClass('active'))
            {
                el.removeClass('active');
            }
        }
        if (!el.hasClass('active') && type == -1)
        {
            el.addClass('active');
            $('.slide-2').addClass('active');
            window.run_animate = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.run_animate = false;
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        }
        if (window.run_animate === true)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if (this.pageYOffset == 0)
    {
        $('body').trigger('mousewheel',[1]);
    } else {
        $('body').trigger('mousewheel',[-1]);
    }
});
```

P.S. Вдруг кому-то пригодиться. Я нашла решение, которое более-менее мне подходит

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1200) {
    $('.slide_animated').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (ev) {
        $('body').addClass('fixed-header');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var $this = $(this),
            scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
            scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
            height = $this.height(),
            delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
            ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
            up = delta > 0;

        var prevent = function () {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
            // Scrolling down, but this will take us past the bottom.
            $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);

            return prevent();
        } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
            // Scrolling up, but this will take us past the top.
            $this.scrollTop(0);
            return prevent();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: На этом сайте, skyservice2016.ru, когда сьезжает верхний слайдер, прокрутка не изменяет своего положения. Не знаю как точно это состояние описать, прошу прощения, не разбираюсь в javascript.

Comment: "но как быть с тем, что бы прокрутка не скроллилась, не придумаю".
Поясните, пожалуйста. Непонятно.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/efl9qd
Извините, не знаю как толково обьяснить

Answer (score 0):

возможно  все завязано на это ...

CSS3 трансформации изменяют размер, форму и положение элемента 
на веб-странице с помощью свойства transform. Трансформации преобразовывают
 элемент, не затрагивая остальные элементы веб-страницы, т.е. другие элементы
 не сдвигаются относительно него. По умолчанию трансформация происходит 
 относительно центра элемента.

К элементам, которые могут быть трансформированы, 
относятся элементы с display: block; и display: inline-block;, 
а также элементы, значение свойства display которых вычисляется как table-row,
 table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell или 
 table-caption. Трансформированным считается элемент 
 с любым установленным значением свойства transform, отличным от none.

когда съезжает верхний слайдер
на странице меняются свойства у след элементов

div class="gr-6 slide_animated ng-scope"

div class="gr-6 slide_animated ng-scope active"

.gr-0, .gr-1, .gr-2, .gr-3, .gr-4, .gr-5, .gr-6

```
display: inline-block;
```

.slide_animated

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
```

.slide_animated.active

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

https://html5book.ru/css3-transform/

Comment: вот здесь все подробно описано про прокрутку 
https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel